# ADB Logcat returns a strange message

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I have Android installed on Ubuntu Studio 14.04, all good, all ok. Usually I'm reading commands from console with `adb logcat`. It is very comfortable.

However, I suddenly started getting the following messages:

```
gtobar@gtobar-Inspiron-N4050:~$ adb logcat
    Notice!!!!       
The logger function is disabled at default in your user versio! 
To open this function please refer to the following setps: 
to enable log_main:     echo y > /proc/logger/log_main 
to enable log_events:  echo y > /proc/logger/log_events 
to enable log_radio:    echo y > /proc/logger/log_radio 
to enable log_system:   echo y > /proc/logger/log_system
```

Does anyone have any idea?. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Looks like your logging is disabled. Have you tried executing those commands that were suggested?

Comment: Specifically, open an adb shell and try executing them.  Or you can see if you can pass it through quoted, ie `adb shell "echo y > /proc/logger/log_main"`